# cannot remove python 3.3.3

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, python3

> sudo apt-get install python-apt

returning error:

> python-apt : Depends: python (<2.8) but 3.3.3-1 is to be installed

I have removed python3 from the machine using apt-get

When I run:

> dpkg-query --list

I get the following for python:

```
ri python 3.3.3-1 python-3.3.3
ii python2.7 2.7.3-0ubuntu3
```

but by running python --version

> Python 2.7.3

How can I remove any of the python 3.3.3-1 references/packages from my system?

```
 apt-cache policy python python2 python3
python:
  Installed: 3.3.3-1
  Candidate: 3.3.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.3.3-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
python3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.3-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
N: Unable to locate package python2
```

After Byte Commander's comment:

```
 apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `apt policy python python2 python3` to your question, please? But most importantly, don't mess with the Python if you are not sure what you are doing! Many of Ubuntu's applications (like e.g. the `apt` package manager itself) depend on Python and will no longer work after you remove it. The goal here is not to uninstall Python (except if you installed additional Pythons yourself, but not the system packages).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean apt-cache policy? I've added it above.

Comment: Okay, so for whatever reason you have a `python` package in your local package cache which provides Python 3, although it should be Python 2. If you hopefully haven't messed up too much yet and `apt-get` still works, try running this: `sudo apt-get install python=2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 python3` and remove your cached packages with `sudo apt-get clean` afterwards. Please reply back whether it worked and post its output, together with the output of `apt-cache policy python` again.

Comment: After everything got fixed again, you should probably also check your `/var/log/apt/history.log` and see which packages got removed when you uninstalled `python3` earlier (which you should not have done) and reinstall them again.

Comment: fwiw, whenever you think you need to do something with a Python installation, consider using Docker. Alpine Linux is only about 8MB. Because messing with the default Python installation on Debian/Ubuntu can result in the OS no longer working.

Comment: True, but when I first wrote the code that required phython 3 docker wasn't really a big thing ;) wrote it back in like 2013 or something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so for whatever reason you have a `python` package in your local package cache which provides Python 3, although it should be Python 2.

If you hopefully haven't messed up too much yet and `apt-get` still works, try running this:

```
sudo apt-get install python=2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 python3
```

and remove your cached packages with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

afterwards.

After everything got fixed again, you should probably also check your `/var/log/apt/history.log` and see which packages got removed when you uninstalled `python3` earlier (which you should not have done) and reinstall them again.